# Why anchor tag applies on some area of image?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am working on a project http://www.node.au.com/  The problem that i am facing is that i have a logo image around which there is an anchor tag, but when i hover over logo it applies only on the area on left side but not on whole image i searched a lot for the solution but no luck can any one send me the solution.

kindly hover mouse on left side of image and see the issue  many thanks in advance.

here is the code:

```
<a  href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>"><img style="margin-left:-17px;margin-top:20px;"src="http://www.node.au.com/wp-content/themes/folio-two/images/main-logo.png" alt="NODE &ndash; 3D Visualisation"></a>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "but when i hover over logo it applies only on the area on left side but not on whole image"?

Comment: i mean that i want to make full image as and anchor not only small part of iamge

Answer (score 0):

2 things:
1. add "display:block;" to the  tag, this will allow it to be as large as the image within.
2. The  (menu) is covering it, making it unclickable. Remove the margin-top: -130px, and you'll be able to click it fine.

I have no idea why there's all that space at the top of that UL, though. It looks like you don't need a UL, in any case, and can just use a div, since there's only one li element within it.

-Julian

Comment: yes are right Mr.julian but if i will remove margin the menu will go down which will cause another issue

Comment: Taking this out should help:
#sidebar .menu {
position: absolute;
bottom: 7%;
}

Comment: Apply Ankit's ".logo" class to the <a> tag, instead of the <img> tag

Answer (score 0):

```
use this class on logo image


.logo {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    margin-left: -17px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: check it i apply it but still the problem exists